# How to implement a custom Key generating function in EF Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

While working on a project I've stumbled the problem of having to implement a function that generates an unique identifier similar to a natural composite key. I've tried to illustrate the situation as best I can in the code below. I'm not instantiating objects below, since I just wanted to show the structure and method for generating the Key.

```
// Define other methods and classes here
public class ClassA
{
    public string ClassAID { get; set; }
    public string CodeA { get; set; }
    public string CodeB { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
    public virtual User user { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string classAID { get; set; }
    public string CodeC { get; set; }

    public virtual ClassA ClassA { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public string userID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OfficeID { get; set; }
}

// The function to generate the ID for both classes:
public string GenerateClassAID(User user)
{
    string classAID = user.OfficeID + ClassB.CodeC + /*incrementing number*/ + DateTime.Now.Year;

    return classAID;
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out where to best locate the generating function. Especially since both entities are created in one process. Would the DbContext class be the best place to put this in? There are more classes like ClassB, and I need to be able to call the function to generate their ID while trying to not repeat code.

Comment: How are `User` and `ClassA`/`ClassB` related? Are there many `Users` per `ClassA` or many `ClassA` per `User`? Also, if there is a one-to-one relationship for ClassA and ClassB, why include the ClassAID property on both classes?

Comment: ClassA has a User. One-to-one. There are also classes similar to ClassB, like ClassC, ClassD; All of them share the ClassAID as their primary key.